# How to stop else showing as default on basic PHP login script

Tags: php, forms, authentication, if-statement

I am using `PHP` to build a very basic `login script`. However, the `else` from the `ifelse statement` shows by default before the user has even clicked `log in`. 
Before the user has even tried to login they are greeted with this:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/madhous3/public_html/dev/admin/index.php:12) in /home/madhous3/public_html/dev/admin/login.php on line 13
Sorry, please try again.
```

How do I stop this? However, if the user enters the details correctly, they are directed to the right page.

Code

index.php

```
   <?php 
        include("login.php"); 
        ?>
        <h1>Admin Area Login</h1>



        <form method="post" action="login.php">
        Username<input type="text" name="username" />
        Password<input type="text" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="log_in" value="Log In" />

        </form>
```

login.php

```
<?php 

$username_inputted = $_POST['username'];
$password_inputted = $_POST['password'];


if($username_inputted == 'admin' && $password_inputted == 'password'){

header("location:login_success.php");


}else{
header("location:index.php");
echo "Sorry, please try again."; 
}



?>
```

Comment: How can you have an `echo` after a redirect?

Comment: It goes from the form, to the login script, and if the user is unsuccesful, they are taken back to the login page (index.php) and the echo is displayed. That was the hope anyway.

Comment: What will happen is `login attempt` -> `failed login` -> `redirect to index.php` and not `login attempt` -> `failed login` -> `redirect to index.php` -> `echo "Sorry, please try again."`

Comment: Yer, I realise that now. What I have done now is just: login attempt -> failed login -> login_failed.php or login attempt -> login_success.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the include("login.php") from index.php.

Instead, you should redirect back to index.php from your login.php with a flag specifying that the user entered the wrong information (if they failed the login).

index.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fail'])) {
        echo 'Login failed.';
    }
?>
<h1>Admin Area Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
Username<input type="text" name="username" />
Password<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="submit" name="log_in" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php 

$username_inputted = $_POST['username'];
$password_inputted = $_POST['password'];

if($username_inputted == 'admin' && $password_inputted == 'password'){
    header("location:login_success.php");
} else {
    header("location:index.php?fail=1");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so what's happening is that in index.php you're including login.php at the start.  At that time it imports everything from login.php.  Since you're including it, the script is going to run.

At the load of the page index.php, the script on login.php starts.  It defines those variables $username_inputted & $password_inputted as null, since the POST hasn't happened yet.  Then the if block checks, finds null variables, then the else block fires since the variables aren't equal to the expected login info because they're null.

Therefore the echo fires and is displayed on the screen before anything is POSTed.

Nav_nav's solution should work well, since the only time the 'bad login' echo will be displayed is if someone entered something into the input fields, I just wanted to give you a rundown of the algorithm's reason for messing up.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    //define input vars
      $username_inputted = $_POST['username'];
      $password_inputted = $_POST['password'];


      if($username_inputted == 'admin' && $password_inputted == 'password'){
        header("location:login_success.php");
      }else{

        header("location:index.php");
        echo "Sorry, please try again."; 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the header('location:login.php'). You can't send a header if you've already started sending any HTML to the browser. And if it did work, you'd get an endless loop of reloads.

Then:
You could check for $_POST ['submit'] and if it doesnt exist then don't show them the try again message.